# Python - Не останавливается функция

Tags: python, асинхронность

Пишу асинхронного бота в телеграм, при поступлении нового сообщения вызываю функцию

```
    if event.is_private:
        await Parser(event)

async def Parser(event):
#много строк кода поэтому просто приведу такой пример
```

функция выполняется как надо, но спустя несколько секунд выполняется снова и снова

в коде уже имеется точно такой-же вызов функции, вызывается так-же, а вот работает идеально, один раз как положено.

помогите разобраться чайнику :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы прописали «if event.is_private» без четкого условия. То есть, значение принимается, как True, поэтому Ваша функция “async def Parser” вызывается постоянно. Пропишите условие нормальное, чтоб функция не вызывалось постоянно.